# Logoff отключившихся пользователей после x-минут простоя

Tags: powershell

Есть скрипт, который отключает пользователя после 15 минут простоя, как мне сделать, чтобы он отключал только отключившихся пользователей, а не всех, ведь например некоторые пользователи просто сворачивают окно

```
#Путь к списку серверов RDS в формате txt
$path_list_srv = "c:\server.txt"
#Время позволенное на АФК ( МИНУТЫ )
$Idle_minutes = 15
# VIP
[array]$excep_login_list
$excep_login_list = Get-Content -Path "c:\vip.txt"
#Загрузка списка серверов
$Servers = $Null
$Servers = Get-Content -Path $path_list_srv
#Если список серверов пуст то выход
if ($Servers -eq $Null) {exit}
 
foreach($Srv in $Servers){
 
    #Получаем данные с сервера RDS о сессиях 
    $List_i = $Null
    $List_i =  quser /server:$Srv
 
    #Обработка данных сессий
    foreach ($i in $List_i){
    Get-Variable -Name "u_*" | Clear-Variable
    $u_array = $i -split " " | ? {$_}
    $u_login = $u_array[0]
    $u_session = $u_array[1]
    $u_Idle_t = $u_array[$u_array.count-3] 
 
    #Преобразование idle time в временной формат
    if ($u_Idle_t -ne $Null){
      $u_Idle_t = $u_Idle_t -replace "\+",":" -replace "\.","0:0" -replace "Disc","0:0"
      if($u_Idle_t -like "*:*"){
        $u_Idle_t = [timespan]"$($u_Idle_t)"
        }elseif($u_Idle_t -eq "." -or $u_Idle_t -eq "none"){
        $u_Idle_t = [timespan]"0:0"
        }else{
        $u_Idle_t = [timespan]"0:$($u_Idle_t)"
      }
      #FIX БАГА
      if ( [int]$u_Idle_t.Days -gt 1000){$u_Idle_t = New-TimeSpan}
    }
    #Если ВИП
    if ( ($excep_login_list | Where-Object {$_ -eq $u_login}) -ne $NUll){$u_Idle_t = New-TimeSpan}

 
    #Если idle time превышает заданный интервал то сессия отключается
     if ([int]$u_Idle_t.TotalMinutes -ge $Idle_minutes){
      write-host -ForegroundColor yellow $Srv : $u_login / $u_Idle_t.TotalMinutes
      logoff /SERVER:$Srv $u_session
      }ELSE{write-host -ForegroundColor green $Srv : $u_login / $u_Idle_t.TotalMinutes}
 
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем скрипт? сервер терминальный? обычный RDS?

Comment: Да, из-за того что некоторых пользователей нельзя категорически отключать, нужно скрипт, чтобы была выборка, мне нужно чтобы люди которые отключись от сервера полностью отключались по истечению 15 минут, этот скрипт отключает даже если пользователь в сети, но бездействует 15 минут

Comment: не проще всех выгонять политикой? а тем, кто не должен быть отключен написать скрипт/приложение которое будет эмулировать нагрузку (двигать курсор на пиксель туда и обратно, или обращаться к ресурсу сетевому периодически вобщем ввод вывод производить?) и их выкидывать не будет политикой?

Comment: One idea maybe to set a task scheduler to run a task "logoff", to activate the task even someone logs on and triggers when the machine is in idle for 120 min.

Comment: короче правильная мысль сделай таску для нужных тебе юзеров, которых надо выгонять, через GPO,и при простое (условие в триггере задачи) (как вариант брать текущий логин и из ldap читать аттрибут касательно RDP-сессии)  вызывай в экшене таски shutdown /l /f /t 30.

Comment: Это нужно таску сделать для каждого пользователя? У меня их штук 15-20, это ладно, но если бы их было 500? Или я что-то не понимаю

Comment: зачем сделай таску для пользователей всех твоих терминалов в групповой политике раздел планировщик заданий. повесь ее на нужные сервера. добавь в скрипте проверки для исключения пользователей которых низзя, к примеру сделай группу и проверяй в скрипте что их в ней нет. на PS это можно сделать в пару строк кода.

Comment: $id = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$groups = $id.Groups | foreach-object {
 $_.Translate([Security.Principal.NTAccount])
}
if ($groups -contains "YOURDOMAIN\PRIVILEDGED_GROUP") {
 "You're a member of Super users, skip"
}else { shutdown /t 0 /f /l }

Answer (score 0):

Можно взять готовый кусок отсюда создав из него модуль https://github.com/bkuppens/powershell/blob/master/Logoff-DisconnectedSession.ps1 либо надергав то, что нужно.

```
function Get-Sessions
{
   $queryResults = query session
   $starters = New-Object psobject -Property @{"SessionName" = 0; "UserName" = 0; "ID" = 0; "State" = 0; "Type" = 0; "Device" = 0;}
   foreach ($result in $queryResults)
   {
      try
      {
         if($result.trim().substring(0, $result.trim().indexof(" ")) -eq "SESSIONNAME")
         {
            $starters.UserName = $result.indexof("USERNAME");
            $starters.ID = $result.indexof("ID");
            $starters.State = $result.indexof("STATE");
            $starters.Type = $result.indexof("TYPE");
            $starters.Device = $result.indexof("DEVICE");
            continue;
         }

         New-Object psobject -Property @{
            "SessionName" = $result.trim().substring(0, $result.trim().indexof(" ")).trim(">");
            "Username" = $result.Substring($starters.Username, $result.IndexOf(" ", $starters.Username) - $starters.Username);
            "ID" = $result.Substring($result.IndexOf(" ", $starters.Username), $starters.ID - $result.IndexOf(" ", $starters.Username) + 2).trim();
            "State" = $result.Substring($starters.State, $result.IndexOf(" ", $starters.State)-$starters.State).trim();
            "Type" = $result.Substring($starters.Type, $starters.Device - $starters.Type).trim();
            "Device" = $result.Substring($starters.Device).trim()
         }
      } 
      catch 
      {
         $e = $_;
         Write-Output "ERROR: " + $e.PSMessageDetails
      }
   }
}

$DisconnectedSessions = Get-Sessions | ? {$_.State -match $IncludeStates -and $_.UserName -ne ""} | Select ID, UserName
foreach ($session in $DisconnectedSessions)
{
   logoff /SERVER:$Srv $session.ID
}
```